# MVC Area routing not calling base area controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am using the areas in MVC my RouteConfig file has only the following route

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
var route = routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "Srd.Controllers" }
);
route.DataTokens["area"] = "Users";
```

Which is redirecting to "Users" area by default

my problem is in the view, I have the following action which is showing the error.

```
@Html.Action("SetPermissions", "SetSession", new { Area = "" });
```

No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Any help.

Comment: try this: @Html.Action("SetPermissions", "SetSession", new { area = "" },null);

Comment: It is showing syntax error